# How should text nodes with CDATA and whitespace be interpreted in XML?

Tags: c#, xml

The System.Xml parsing features had a few surprises for me in store, and I wonder how the following *should* be interpreted, or if this is "up to the implementation":

**Version 1**:

```xml
<root><elem>
    <![CDATA[MyValue]]>
</elem></root>
```

**Version 2:**

```xml
<root><elem>
    -<![CDATA[MyValue]]>-
</elem></root>
```

**What *should* be the value of `elem`?** Or is it okay that this depends on the implementation that parses it, and should I just deal with that?

I expected (at first) that in both cases all whitespace between the start/end node and the first non-whitespace character would be ignored. This is not the case, but failing that, I would've at least expected it to *never* be ignored, but this is also not the case. See full repro below for my expectations.

---

To elaborate...

Two cases had me stumped when I tested them:

- `XDocument.Parse` will suddenly start to include the `\n\t` whitespace in example 2, whereas it ignored it in example 1.
- `XDocument.Load` with `new XmlReaderSettings {IgnoreWhitespace = true}` will behave similarly.

What gives? Is this just the implementation being (to my taste) quirky, and/or is this specified behavior?

Here's a full repro of my expectations (fresh C# class library project with latest NUnit package from NuGet):

```
[TestFixture]
public class XmlTests
{
    public static XDocument ParseDocument(string input)
    {
        return XDocument.Parse(input);
    }

    public static XDocument LoadDocument(Stream stream)
    {
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings() { IgnoreWhitespace = false }); // Default
        return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
    }

    public static XDocument LoadDocument_IgnoreWhitespace(Stream stream)
    {
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings() { IgnoreWhitespace = true });
        return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
    }

    const string example1 = "<root><elem>\n\t<![CDATA[MyValue]]>\n</elem></root>";
    const string example2 = "<root><elem>\n\t-<![CDATA[MyValue]]>-\n</elem></root>";

    [Test]
    public void A_Parsing_Example1_WorksAsExpected()
    {
        var doc = ParseDocument(example1);
        var element = doc.Descendants("elem").Single();
        Assert.That(element.Value, Is.EqualTo("MyValue"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void B_Loading_Example1_WorksAsExpected()
    {
        var doc = LoadDocument(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example1)));
        var element = doc.Descendants("elem").Single();
        Assert.That(element.Value, Is.EqualTo("\n\tMyValue\n"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void C_LoadingWithIgnoreWhitespace_Example1_WorksAsExpected()
    {
        var doc = LoadDocument_IgnoreWhitespace(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example1)));
        var element = doc.Descendants("elem").Single();
        Assert.That(element.Value, Is.EqualTo("MyValue"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void D_Parsing_Example2_WorksAsExpected()
    {
        var doc = ParseDocument(example2);
        var element = doc.Descendants("elem").Single();
        Assert.That(element.Value, Is.EqualTo("-MyValue-"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void E_Loading_Example2_WorksAsExpected()
    {
        var doc = LoadDocument(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example2)));
        var element = doc.Descendants("elem").Single();
        Assert.That(element.Value, Is.EqualTo("\n\t-MyValue-\n"));
    }

    [Test]
    public void F_LoadingWithIgnoreWhitespace_Example2_WorksAsExpected()
    {
        var doc = LoadDocument_IgnoreWhitespace(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example2)));
        var element = doc.Descendants("elem").Single();
        Assert.That(element.Value, Is.EqualTo("MyValue"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDATAs are difficult. They are not changed by the parser (read). They are not allowed to include invalid characters or `]]>`. However some implementations will change them to generate valid XML output (write).

The content of `elem` depends on the parser and if it ignores the whitespace nodes. `elem` has 3 child nodes.

1. whitespace text node with content "`\n\t`"
2. cdata section node with content "`MyValue`"
3. whitespace text node with content "`\n`"

So like you noticed if the whitespace nodes are ignored, only the cdata remains. In you second example the result would be different (If repaired).

1. text node with content "`\n\t-`"
2. cdata section node with content "`MyValue`"
3. text node with content "`-\n`"

The first and third node now have non whitespace content (the -). They are no whitespace nodes any more and not ignored depending on the option.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, with the TextNode-Cdata-TextNode way of things it all makes sense.